# Perl fork manager get the output variable after completing the forking

Tags: linux, perl, parallel-processing, fork

I am very new to the Perl Parallel Fork manager. Here is the code,

```
    my $max_procs = 3;
    my $forking =  Parallel::ForkManager->new($max_procs);

    my @collect_processed_data;
    foreach my $row (@data_array) {

       $forking->start and next;

       # Code processing -- Started

       push(@collect_processed_data, $obtained_data);

       # where $obtained_data is an array which we get it from DB. 

       # Code Processing -- Ended. 

       #print Dumper @collect_processed_data; --> Works here. 

       $forking->finish; # do the exit in the child process

    }

    $forking->wait_all_children;

    print Dumper @collect_processed_data; --> But not working here;
```

Here is the issue, The forking works fine here. But the issue i am not able to collect the collect the data outside in the foreach loop. But at the same time, i am able to collect before "$forking->finish"

Is there any anything i need to do with "$forking->finish;"?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone suggest why this question got down vote?

Answer (score 3):

Everything between `$pm->start` and `$pm->finish` execute in a fork of the parent. You're adding to the child's copy of `@collect_processed_data`, but printing the parent's `@collect_processed_data`.

P::FM provides a mechanism for returning data back to the parent, which is documented under the heading "[RETRIEVING DATASTRUCTURES from child processes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager#RETRIEVING-DATASTRUCTURES-from-child-processes)".

```
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($max_procs);

my @collect_processed_data;
$pm->run_on_finish(sub {
   my ($pid, $exit_code, $ident, $exit_signal, $core_dump, $processed_data) = @_;

   if ($exit_signal) { warn("$pid killed by signal $exit_signal\n"); }
   elsif ($exit_code) { warn("$pid exited with error $exit_code\n"); }

   push @collect_processed_data, $processed_data
      if defined($processed_data);
});

for (...) {
   $pm->start and next;
   ...
   my $processed_data = ...;
   ...
   $pm->finish(0, $processed_data);
}
```